# java.net.connectexception when sending string request

Tags: java, web-services, batch-processing, wildfly, connection-timeout

In my batch application when I am sending requests across a network using a Web Service and Java, after running about 30000 requests and receiving the responses, the program throws a java.net.connectexception connection timed out exception.

I am using WildFly, along with some Java code in the middle to configure the requests (Strings) before sending it across the network.

After research the possible reasons I found for this is that there is either a Firewall blocking my access, which can't be true since it ran 90% of the requests already.

I've also seen somewhere that says that I could have overloaded the server, although I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: Could the remote server be blocking requests (after a point) because it sees your requests as spam or some sort of Denial of Service?

Comment: @Lawrence Tierney it worked this morning, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

You have filled up the server's listen backlog queue. This is caused by creating new connections faster than the server can accept them. You should look into connection pooling at the client, and handling multiple requests per connection at the server.

Comment: it worked this morning, but I'm going to look into that thanks. Even though in the past it had successfully completed 100 thousand files, this was probably just one of those days